# echo multiple responses from mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I would like to echo various responses from a mySQL database without repeating them.

The table looks like this:

```
+----+----------+---------------------+----------+
| id | user     | timestamp           | champion |
+----+----------+---------------------+----------+
| 1  | Watrasei | 2015-11-13 22:31:27 | yasuo    |
+----+----------+---------------------+----------+
| 2  | Meta Nex | 2016-04-29 02:47:33 | yasuo    |
+----+----------+---------------------+----------+
| 3  | Meta Nex | 2016-04-30 02:27:53 | yasuo    |
+----+----------+---------------------+----------+
```

When I type this code directly into phpMyAdmin the response is the expected one:

```
SELECT DISTINCT user FROM champions3 WHERE champion = 'yasuo'
```

[image: sql response]

However, when I use this PHP code to make the request and the echo the results, only the last result is shown:

```
<?php
$dbconnect = new MySQLi("localhost","root","pass","database");
if ($dbconnect ->connect_errno){
    die("Connection failed: " . $dbconnect ->connect_error);
}

$creatorSQL = "
    SELECT DISTINCT user 
    FROM champions3 
    WHERE champion = 'yasuo'
";
$creatorQuery = $dbconnect->query($creatorSQL);

// Convert all results into variables. If there is more than one result, put a comma in front of the name.
$i = 1;
while ($creator = mysqli_fetch_assoc($creatorQuery)) {
    if($i = 1) {
        ${'author'.$i} = '<a>'.$creator["user"].'</a>';
    }
    else {
        ${'author'.$i} = ', <a>'.$creator["user"].'</a>';
    }
    $i++;
}

echo $author1, $author2, $author3, $author4, $author5, $author6, $author7;

mysqli_close($dbconnect);
?>
```

[image: Real result]

The expected result should be: Meta Nex, Watrasei

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `if($i == 1)` 2equals not 1

Comment: OMG IM SO RETARD, thank you, I was starting to become crazy

Comment: we are all crazy brother ;-)

Comment: oh look at all the bottom feeders

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$dbconnect = new MySQLi("localhost","root","pass","database");
if ($dbconnect ->connect_errno){
    die("Connection failed: " . $dbconnect ->connect_error);
}

$creatorSQL = "
    SELECT DISTINCT user 
    FROM champions3 
    WHERE champion = 'yasuo'
";
$creatorQuery = $dbconnect->query($creatorSQL);

// Convert all results into variables. If there is more than one result, put a comma in front of the name.
$i = 1;
while ($creator = mysqli_fetch_assoc($creatorQuery)) {
    if($i == 1) {
        ${'author'.$i} = '<a>'.$creator["user"].'</a>';
    }
    else {
        ${'author'.$i} = ', <a>'.$creator["user"].'</a>';
    }
    $i++;
}

echo $author1, $author2, $author3, $author4, $author5, $author6, $author7;

mysqli_close($dblogin);
?>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate what you changed and why? This code may or may not work, but you should explain it so that this constitutes a real answer.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

Check your mysqli_close()

For reference :

```
<?php
$dbconnect = new mysqli("localhost","root","123456","testing");
if ($dbconnect ->connect_errno){
    die("Connection failed: " . $dbconnect ->connect_error);
}

$creatorSQL = "
    SELECT DISTINCT name 
    FROM user_detail 
    WHERE Age = 23
";
$creatorQuery = $dbconnect->query($creatorSQL);

// Convert all results into variables. If there is more than one result, put a comma in front of the name.
while ($creator = mysqli_fetch_assoc($creatorQuery)) {
    $author[] = $creator['name'];
}

echo implode(', ', $author);

mysqli_close($dbconnect);
?>
```